# Can't use tikz in CVPR template

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to use tikz to create graphic in CVPR template. When I add just `\usepackage{tikz}`, there is compile error. Someone suggests that delete `cvpr_eso.sty` and `eso-pic.sty`. I did that and now I can use tikz, but there is another compile error said "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). Missing number, treated as zero". It looks like this is caused by the file I deleted. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome, please give a Minimum Working Example (MWE): [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I download the CVPR style from  http://cvpr2020.thecvf.com/submission/main-conference/author-guidelines, remove `eso-pic.sty` and put `\usepackage{tikz}` together with the other `\usepackage` statements in the example document provided by the template, then I can add TikZ drawings without any error. So probably the error you get is a mistake somewhere in the code of your document, that is unrelated to package loading. If you can add an example document to your question here that actually reproduces the error then we may be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Actually if you compile `egpaper_final.tex` you get no errors, but if you try with `egpaper_for_review.tex` you get the error that Yingdong described. My conjecture is that Tikz conflicts with the line numbering.

Comment: I didn't see eso-pic.sty in the new 2022 template, but again the template doesn't support tikz. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cvpr2022-official-latex-template/bphmxkmtqzjh

Answer (score 1):

The issue still remains in the CVPR 2022 style. Since eso-pic is now hardcoded in the style-file, there is no chance of deleting the old eso-pic.sty.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [here](https://github.com/MCG-NKU/CVPR_Template/issues/3), adding these lines at the beginning of the preamble can help:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@everyshi.sty}{}
\makeatother
```